# Angular - display updated behaviorsubject value in template when value changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a boolean BehaviorSubject whose value I want to use in my template:

```
isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

in ngOnInit, I subscribe to it:

```
this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe((result) => {
  console.log('result', result);
});
```

Following that (in the ngOnInit), I have a service call that returns a promise. When that is done, I set the behavior subject value:

```
  this.authService.isLoggedIn().then((loggedIn) => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      this.isLoggedIn$.next(loggedIn);
      console.log('loggedIn', loggedIn);
      // set the user model value here...
    }
  });
```

Lastly, I am displaying this value in the template:

```
<span>{{ isLoggedIn$ | async }}</span>
```

However, even though the console is showing the value changing, the template is not updating. I tried ngAfterViewInit and change detection and nothing seems to work. I assume the reason the value isn't updating in the template is becasue angular doesn't think anything has changed when the behavior subject is updated.

Am I missing something?

The problem is it might take a second or two to get the value back from the authService.isLoggedIn promise and if it is delayed longer that, the template wont display data (login info, like the user name) from the promise. The only thing that works is if I use a setTimeout() wrapper around the service call, which I would prefer not to do.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: here is the whole component, adding the Observable as suggested by Brandon. Still doesn't work though:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IUserModel } from './_interfaces/user';
import { AppService } from './_services/app.service';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  apiUser?: IUserModel;
  isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isLoggedInOb: Observable<boolean> = new Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly appService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoggedInOb.subscribe((result) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = result;
      console.log('result', result);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.authService.isLoggedIn().then((loggedIn) => {
        this.isLoggedIn$.next(loggedIn);
        this.isLoggedInOb = this.isLoggedIn$.asObservable();
        console.log('loggedIn', loggedIn);

        this.appService.lastActivityDatetimeSubject$.subscribe((data) => {
          this.lastActivityDatetime = data;
        });
      });
    }, 0);

    this.appService.apiUserSubject$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.apiUser = data;
    });

  }

  login(): void {
    this.authService.login();
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
}
```

If I set the setTimeout to 1000 milliseconds, it works but not if I remove the setTimeout  function.

Here is the template:

```
<header>
  <div class="header-group-1">
    <a href="index.html" class="header-logo-link">
      <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="header-logo-img" alt="Company Logo" />
    </a>
    <div class="header-logo-text-wrapper">
      <span class="header-logo-text-top">Company Name</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="header-group-2">
      <div class="header-app-name">
        <span>App Name</span>
      </div>
      <div class="header-greeting">
        <span *ngIf="apiUser && isLoggedIn && apiUser.FirstName">Hello {{apiUser.FirstName}} {{apiUser.LastName}}!</span>
        <button class="focus-dark" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" mat-stroked-button (click)="login()">Login</button>
        <button class="focus-dark" *ngIf="isLoggedIn" mat-stroked-button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
        
        {{ isLoggedInOb | async }} <--- this is what I am trying to have updated when the behavior subject is updated
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="router-outlet-content" role="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="footer-first-row">
    <a href="/disclaimer">Disclaimer</a>
    <span class="divider" aria-hidden="true">|</span>
    <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a>
    <span class="divider" aria-hidden="true">|</span>
    <a href="/terms-conditions">Terms and Conditions</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: In the console, you're seeing "result false, result true, loggedIn true", right?

Comment: yes, that is correct. The console is logging the new value

Comment: fixing the problem by settimeout is a sign of change detection issue, could you create a minimum demo on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I typically provide an observable for the Subject/BehaviorSubject:

```js
isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor() {
  this.loggedIn$ = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();
}
```

Then components subscribe to the observable, not the Subject/BehaviorSubject directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brandon. I still have the same issue though. I posted more code in the event I am missing something

Comment: You need to populate the observable from the behavior subject in the constructor of the component. Is there a particular reason you're using a promise for `isLoggedIn()`?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're going to need to check if the user is logged in elsewhere in your application? If so, you're going to want to move that BehaviorSubject/Observable to a serve instead of defining them in a component

Comment: Ok, I will try putting it in the constructor. The service using the promise is coming from our IDP server (identity server) so I don't think I have the ability to change that. It is using an OidcClient library

Comment: Yeah, I may make it a service but I just wanted to keep it simple for a proof of concept.

Comment: If I have a legacy promise to deal with, I use `lastValueFrom`: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom, assuming you're using Rxjs 7

Comment: using Rxjs 7.5.0. I will check it out your link. Thanks again. BTW, I moved the IDP service (with the promise) to the constructor and have the same issue. Except this time the value is false once in the constructor (based on the console log), then changes to true and the ngoninit is always true but the view always shows false unless I refresh the page. weird.

Comment: I may be able to help you more if we did some live coding over WebEx, etc. Please ping me at alsoicode@gmail.com and we'll see if we can find a time that works.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, that is really generous of you. I might take you up on that, probably after the thanksgiving holiday. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Ping me anytime. Hope you have a very nice Thanksgiving

Answer (score 0):

try to use this logic code :

IN THE SERVICE :

```
private isLoggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new 
BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedIn.asObservable();

isLoggedIn(){
return this.http.post(url).pipe(
map(data)=>{
//...code
this.isLoggedIn.next(data)
//...code
}
)
}
```

IN THE COMPONENT

```
currentUser$:Observable<UserInteface>

ngOnInit(): void {

this.currentUser$= this.service. isLoggedIn$

}
```

IN THE HTML
you can subscribe to it and unsub using the async pipe

```
<div *ngIf="(currentUser$ | async) as user">

{{user.nameExemple}}

//some code 

</div>
```